# Community Bulletin is not showing Hot Meta Questions

Tags: support, community-bulletin

Community Bulletin currently has 3 posts which means [it has space for some Hot Meta Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/), some of which could be [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a3%20is%3aq).

It was fine till yesterday but missing at the moment. Any idea if the team is working on it or probably a bug?

> [image]

Comment: Seems to be fixed (for now...)

Comment: Looks like it was not specific to SO, rather it was network-wide. Even Blog and per-meta featured posts are now visible.